# PCIe MSI Address register

Tags: interrupt, pci-e

If i understand correctly MSI host driver should write it target MSI address to relative remote register. How can i get MSI Address register,MSI Config register and so on? Could you explain me this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient 'rep' points to request clarification of your question yet, so I will answer from perspective of Windows host OS since I don't know your system:  If you are writing a function driver to receive MSI interrupts from a device, you should not access the MSI address/data register in PCIe config space directly.  This should be done by the PCI bus manager driver.  However if you MUST access or inspect some PCIe config space registers, it can be done from within a function driver by creating a IOCTL request and sending up the stack to the bus manager.  If you still need some code for this I can post it.